# Double quotes in OCI8 Ruby

Tags: ruby, oci8

I ve tried but could not, even saw various answers from SO is not helping.

I have a SQL -

```
SELECT 'SSS AS AAA' FROM DD."MIN" WHERE AA = 'AAA'
```

this needs both single and double quotes for long complex query. I am not able to keep this SQl in YAML files. I kept in YAML file as

```
    key: "SELECT 'SSS AS AAA' FROM DD.\"MIN\" WHERE AA = 'AAA'"
```

but after reading YAML, its becoming as

```
    SELECT 'SSS AS AAA' FROM DD.\"MIN" WHERE AA = 'AAA'
```

and so OCI8 is throwing a error.however without double quotes its working, not sure how to resolve it. i tried to GSUB "\" to "", and its not working still.

I've even tried to get keep as below

```
    SELECT 'SSS AS AAA' FROM DD.xxxMINxxx WHERE AA = 'AAA'
```

and replace xxx with " before sending to OCI8, its not working.

i need to define a string in Ruby with double quotes only and no backslash character